# Y Value Between Images Changes Unexpectedly?

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite, variable-assignment

I have a game that has 4 lanes -- boats are to move in pairs from top to bottom, and your character (the dolphin) is supposed to avoid them by pressing the A and D keys. I have the first boat set to start at Y -100, and the second boat at Y -450. When you run the game, the distance between the boats changes with every time they spawn at the top again. Why is this happening? With my understanding, the distance between the pairs of boats should always stay at 350. Can someone help me out please?

MEGA Download for images and SFX: https://mega.nz/fm/zHohiSJD

```
import pygame
import random
import os

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" % (0, 20)  # positions the game tab to the top left portion of the monitor
pygame.init()  # initializes pygame
pygame.display.set_caption("Biomagnification ")
SIZE = W, H = 400, 700  # determining the screen size of the game
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)  # creating a display surface
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # creating a clock

# RGB colours
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BACKGROUND = (94, 194, 222)
STRIPE = (60, 160, 190)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# variables
x1 = 30  # desired X position for the left dolphin/hitbox
x2 = 330  # desired X position for the right dolphin/hitbox
lane1 = 30
lane2 = 130
lane3 = 230
lane4 = 330
y = 530  # desired y value of the hitbox
width, height = (40, 64)  # width and height of the hitbox

toggle1 = 0  # toggle for left dolphin
toggle2 = 0  # toggle for right dolphin

target_x1 = 30
target_x2 = 330
vel_x = 10  # speed at which the dolphins move


def drawScene():
    screen.fill(BACKGROUND)  # fills the background with the colour ((94, 194, 222)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE,
                        ((200, 700), (300, 700), (400, 600), (400, 500)))  # draws the different coloured stripes
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 700), (100, 700), (400, 400), (400, 300)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 500), (0, 600), (400, 200), (400, 100)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 300), (0, 400), (400, 0), (300, 0)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 100), (0, 200), (200, 0), (100, 0)))
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (100, 0), (100, 700), 2)  # draws the white separating lines in the background
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (200, 0), (200, 700), 6)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (300, 0), (300, 700), 2)


# dolphin spritesheet
mainsheet = pygame.image.load("mainsheetSmall.png").convert()  # load in the spritesheet
sheetSize = mainsheet.get_size()  # gets the size of the spritesheet
horiz_cells = 36  # number of horizontal frames/cells in the spritesheet
vert_cells = 1  # number of vertical frames/cells in the spritesheet
cell_width = int(sheetSize[0] / horiz_cells)  # determining the width of each cell
cell_height = int(sheetSize[1] / vert_cells)  # determing the height of each cell

cellList = []  # creates a list for all the cells
for vert in range(0, sheetSize[1], cell_height):
    for horz in range(0, sheetSize[0], cell_width):
        surface = pygame.Surface((cell_width, cell_height))
        surface.blit(mainsheet, (0, 0),
                     (horz, vert, cell_width, cell_height))
        colorkey = surface.get_at((0, 0))  # gets the colour at O, 0 (white)
        surface.set_colorkey(colorkey)  # removes all the white from the spritesheet, making the background transparent
        cellList.append(surface)  # appends to the list of cells (cellList)

cellPosition = 0  # determines which frame is playing. Starts at 0
```

Code for boat

```
# boat
boatSpeed = 10
boat = pygame.image.load("boat.png").convert_alpha()
boatX = random.choice([lane1, lane2, lane3, lane4])
if boatX == lane1:
    boatX2 = random.choice([lane3, lane4])
elif boatX == lane2:
    boatX2 = random.choice([lane3, lane4])
else:
    boatX2 = random.choice([lane1, lane2])
boatY = -100

boatX3 = random.choice([lane1, lane2, lane3, lane4])
if boatX3 == lane1:
    boatX4 = random.choice([lane3, lane4])
elif boatX3 == lane2:
    boatX4 = random.choice([lane3, lane4])
else:
    boatX4 = random.choice([lane1, lane2])
boatY2 = -450
```

.

```
# main loop
while True:
    clock.tick(60)  # makes the game tick 60 frames per second

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:  # detects if the user presses the ESC key
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:  # detects if the user presses the A key
                pygame.mixer.music.load('percussiveHit.mp3')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                toggle1 += 1  # adds 1 to toggle1
                if toggle1 % 2 == 1:  # if toggle1 mod 2 equals 1
                    target_x1 += 100  # add 100 to the target position
                else:
                    target_x1 -= 100  # if toggle1 mod 2 does not equal 1, subtract 100 from the target position making it the original of 30
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:  # detects if the user presses the D key
                pygame.mixer.music.load('percussiveHit.mp3')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                toggle2 += 1  # adds 1 to toggle2
                if toggle2 % 2 == 1:  # if toggle2 mod 2 equals 1
                    target_x2 -= 100  # subtract 100 the to target position
                else:
                    target_x2 += 100  # if toggle2 mod 2 does not equal 1, add 100 to the target position making it the original of 330
    if x1 < target_x1:
        x1 = min(x1 + vel_x, target_x1)
    else:
        x1 = max(x1 - vel_x, target_x1)

    if x2 < target_x2:
        x2 = min(x2 + vel_x, target_x2)
    else:
        x2 = max(x2 - vel_x, target_x2)

    if cellPosition < len(cellList) - 1:
        cellPosition += 1
    else:
        cellPosition = 0
```

second bit of code for boat

```
    boatY += boatSpeed
    if boatY > H:
        boatX == random.choice([lane1, lane2, lane3, lane4])
        if boatX == lane1:
            boatX2 == random.choice([lane3, lane4])
        elif boatX == lane2:
            boatX2 == random.choice([lane3, lane4])
        else:
            boatX2 == random.choice([lane1, lane2])
        boatY = -100

    boatY2 += boatSpeed
    if boatY2 > H:
        boatX3 == random.choice([lane1, lane2, lane3, lane4])
        if boatX3 == lane1:
            boatX4 == random.choice([lane3, lane4])
        elif boatX3 == lane2:
            boatX4 == random.choice([lane3, lane4])
        else:
            boatX3 == random.choice([lane3, lane4])
        boatY2 = -450

    # pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (x1, y, width, height))  # hitbox of left dolphin
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (x2, y, width, height))  # hitbox of right dolphin
    drawScene()  # draws the scene (background, lane-lines, etc)
    # players
    screen.blit(cellList[cellPosition], (x1 + 4, y - 1))  # the left dolphin
    screen.blit(cellList[cellPosition], (x2 + 4, y - 1))  # the right dolphin
    screen.blit(boat, (boatX, boatY))
    screen.blit(boat, (boatX2, boatY))
    screen.blit(boat, (boatX3, boatY2))
    screen.blit(boat, (boatX4, boatY2))
    # screen.blit(boat, (boatX5, boaY3))
    # screen.blit(boat, (boatX6, boatY4))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think it would be best if you took the time to come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and posted that instead of all of your code. In your case, if you find that creating a MCVE is too difficult or not possible, your question might be better suited to a website dedicated to full code review.

Answer (score 0):

`boat-XY` starts at -100
`boat-X2Y2` starts at -450
That's a distance of **350**.
Each step/loop, the boats move 10 (Y += 10).

After 80 steps (dependant on the window size, currently 700), `boat-XY` leaves the screen, moving from position 710, back to -100.

The test is 7**10** because the test is when the Y-position is **>** than 700 (window height).  So you get an off-by-one in this movement too.

At the time `boat-XY` re-starts, `boat-X2Y2` is now at position -450 + 810 → 360.  So now the distance is **460**.

In another 35 steps, `boat-X2Y2` hits the bottom, returning to -450.  At this time, `boat-XY` has advanced 350 steps (from -100) to position 250, making the distance **700**.

And so forth.  As the window size changes, so will this effect.

I think this is quite an interesting effect.  Sure it's not what you wanted, but it incorporates some "clockwork-randomness" to the boats.

Comment: It's definitely not what I want, as if you play the game for long enough all 4 boats will form a wall and it will be impossible to pass. How do I stop this from happening, and  have the distance remain at 350?

Comment: How about just a check to ensure this is not the case. if it *is* the case, move the other boat (preferably while still off-screen) `if boatY == boatY2: boatY2 -= random.randint(100,400)`.  Or maybe add a new control such that the dolphin can "jump" the boat.

Comment: Is like the if `boatY == boatY2: boatY2 -= random.randint(100,400)` idea. Is there a way I can do this without having the boats at the same Y coord? for example, is there a way to have boatY2 reset if it gets within 200 of boatY?

Comment: Something like `if abs( boatY - boatY2 ) > 200: boatY2 -= random.randint(200,400)` ?  That should move it at least 200 away.